# Is it possible to save a variable from javascript to the qualtrics dataset?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am currently working on a qualtrics survey that includes a javascript part. It's basically all set, except I cannot get the response variable from the javascript part to be saved in qualtrics. The variable is a counter of how many times the participant clicked on different options. Is it somehow possible to just add the variable to the dataset?

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySHA3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Lvc.png)

Comment: Send that variable as JSON object property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the embedded data variable in the survey flow.  Then set it in the JavaScript with:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData(variable, value);
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: When I tried it a few days ago this worked perfectly. I tried it again today and it didn't work. Below is the code I am using. I also added screenshots to my original question. Would you have any idea where the problem is?  
var prettyprnt =  selectedCards.join(", ")   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData(Trial, prettyprnt);

Comment: Try it with Trial in quotes like this: Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('Trial', prettyprnt);