# (how) can I tell my JavaScript to append a variable/column to the data Qualtrics exports?

Tags: javascript, arrays, qualtrics, experimental-design

I've implemented a task in Qualtrics that randomly selects a number between 0 and 3, and then selects a corresponding word pool to sample 5 words from. To be able to analyze these data, though, I need to know which 5 words (or at minimum, the index number or name of the word pool being sampled from) is presented to each respondent. Is there a way to implement the recording of this information within JavaScript? Ideally this information would show up when I use Qualtrics' native "export" options, but if I have to somehow create a second spreadsheet with this treatment data, that works just fine as well.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()

{

// first, create four arrays for the four word pools used in task

var wordpool1 = []

var wordpool2 = []

var wordpool3 = []

var wordpool4 = []

// assemble word list arrays into one array, with index 0-3

let masterwordlist = [wordpool1, wordpool2, wordpool3, wordpool4]

// function that randomly chooses an integer between x and y

function randomInteger(min, max) {

 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

}

// function that shuffles (randomizes) a word list array (Fisher-Yates shuffle )

    function shuffle(target){

      for (var i = target.length - 1; i > 0; i--){

        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));

        var temp = target[i];

        target[i] = target[j];

        target[j] = temp;

      }

      return target;

    }

// function that chooses 5 words from a shuffled word list array, returns those 5 words as array

function pickWords(target) {

var randomwords = shuffle(target)

 return randomwords.slice(0, 5);

}

// top-level function 

function genWords(masterlist){

var x = randomInteger(0, 3)

return pickWords(masterlist[x])

}

// actually running the function

randomwords = genWords(masterwordlist)

// save final output as embedded qualtrics data

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("randomwords", randomwords);
```

Is there a way I can have this code record (within Qualtrics or otherwise) which values var x or var randomwords take on?

EDIT: I found another answer on here which may be relevant. According to this answer, though, it looks like I have all the code needed to record my variable selection; do I simply need to set embedded data within the survey flow, as well?
See here: [Is it possible to save a variable from javascript to the qualtrics dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760703/is-it-possible-to-save-a-variable-from-javascript-to-the-qualtrics-dataset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to define the embedded data field randomwords in the survey flow.

Comment: Do I need to define it within the Qualtrics randomizer I’m using to randomize the order the blocks are presented in? (This is necessary because the blocks contain images in addition to the text stimuli.)

Comment: Ah, the solution I mentioned here didn’t work but after some playing with the code I figured it out. Disregard, and thanks for your help!